# How can GMPLS unify signalization plain of all telecommunications network technologies?

Tags: switch, network, protocol-theory, mpls, optics

In what way can GMPLS do that unification of signalization of network technologies, by hardware, like MPLS switches, or by network protocols? And what is the role of optical networks in GMPLS? Are they just one of the technologies that GMPLS integrates with other types of technologies or MPLS directly uses them in their MPLS network infrastructure?

Answer (score 2):

The idea of GMPLS is that it's hardware and media agnostic.  Optical networks are just one kind of media that GMPLS can be used on.